# Disallow ec2 ssh key-pair login but allow a special ssh key to login

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, cloud, packer, cloud-init

I have a use case that my product image only allow a specific ssh keypair (not distribute to customer, only support team has the keypair) to ssh to a VM.

The AMI image is built by packer. Is it possible to ignore the ssh keypair specific during the EC2 creation page but only allow a specific ssh keypair to login?

The reason is that we don't want user to login to the VM and change the configuration; Only support team can ssh into the VM during troubleshooting.

Comment: You could use CloudTrial to detect instance launch and terminate it immediately using lambda if it has any key-pair. Though, I wonder if there is a better way, with some IAM policy permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ssh_redirect_user` to `true` in cloud-init and build in your authized key. This should disable the loading of authorized keys from EC2 meta data.

See https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#users-and-groups

Comment: Is it an option in user-data? How can I configure it so that end user cannot change the value?